# CurrentCellChanged have to click different box to take effect

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm coding in C# and have a DataGridView. I have 9 columns for the user to enter text into, and an add button to add the info to my application. I want to make sure the user enters something in every textbox though, so I have it so it won't do anything if any of them are empty. The problem I'm having however, is when you enter text in the last textbox, it doesn't recognize the current cell has changed unless you click in a different textbox in that row. I want it so that once you enter text it will recognize the cell has changed and the user can immediately enter text in the last box and click add. I'm new to c# and don't know how to do that. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post some of the code you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the DataGrid commits changes after leaving the cell.

If you are binding the columns to properties in your ViewModel use `Binding="{Binding yourProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` so your properties are updated as soon as something changes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As I said, I'm new to c# and visual studio. Could you point me in the right direction on finding the Binding property? Thanks.

Comment: @Kate could you post your source code. Specifically on how you are displaying your properties on the DataGrid

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't post my code due to confidentiality issues with my company. My code doesn't contain any information that would be relevant to my problem, however. I changed all my DataGridView properties in the properties toolbar. It does have a DataBindings section under properties I see. I was messing around with it to see what that did,  but I'm not sure what I should bind it to (or even what binding means). Is there a setting under there that would solve my issue? Or is there actual code I need to write? Again, thanks for the help.